# Incorrect build date format in a maven + spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

In `pom.xml` file, I have below code :

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
</properties>
```

And in `bootstrap.yml` , I am accessing this property like :

```
   build:
   time: @timestamp@
```

The issue is : I am getting the build date in a below format :

```
buildDate   "1496927438064"
```

Please help me to get the correct buildDate.